# How to get attribute value of an element in rtf template using BI publisher

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I have xml like:

```
<row rownumber="1">
 <A.MONETARY_AMOUNT>-8657435577410.93</A.MONETARY_AMOUNT> 
 <A.RECEIPT_NBR>164005044842</A.RECEIPT_NBR> 
 <A.GL_CODE>A.GL_CODE sample data</A.GL_CODE> 
 <A.DESCR1>A.DESCR1 sample data</A.DESCR1> 
 <A.CAMP_RECEIPT_NBR>A.CAMP_REC</A.CAMP_RECEIPT_NBR> 
 <EXPR6_6>2013-04-23</EXPR6_6> 
 <EXPR7_7>2013-04-23</EXPR7_7> 
 <A.EMPLID>A.EMPLID sa</A.EMPLID> 
</row>
```

and I want to get the value of rownumber="1" in rtf template using BI Publisher.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

BI Publisher has extended a set XSL functions for use in RTF templates. So you can try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/row/@rownumber"/>
```

Check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10415_01/doc/bi.1013/e12187/T421739T481158.htm) for more info.